# Return type of a call only using information on types and not on objects

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype, perfect-forwarding, forwarding-reference

Consider the following code:

```
template <class F, class... Args>
void function(F&& f, Args&&... args)
{
    using type1 = decltype(std::forward<F>(f)(std::forwards<Args>(args)...));
    using type2 = decltype(/*equivalent expression but only using types */);
}
```

Is there a way to make `type2` the same as `type1` in all cases but only using the types in the `decltype` expression, or in other words only using `F` and `Args` and not `f` and `args`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you asking for [`std::declval`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval)?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `f` and `args`? Just curious.

Comment: @Rakete1111: this is not an x/y problem, it's just that over the last few years, while writing template metaprogramming code, I asked myself this question several times, and not sure what the answer was (because still after 6 years of playing with them, not sure to understand all the subtelties for universal references and std::forward).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The answer may be based on std::declval yes. But I am not sure if `std::forward<F>(std::declval<F>())` does (and my guess is that it would do the wrong thing)

Comment: Go around the problem with [`std::invoke_result_t<F, Args...>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of)..

Comment: @Vincent Know that a `decltype` expression is never evaluated at runtime. As long as it gets you the right type, you can get away with writing expressions that would otherwise not be valid if evaluated (such as `std::declval` does).

Comment: `std::declval` creates an object/reference to use in `decltype` regardless what the type is. This overcomes issues with say, non default constructible types. In your case, since you already have the objects, there is no need to use `std::declval`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can accomplish this using only C++11 and without decltype using `std::result_of`:

```
using type2 = typename std::result_of<F&&(Args&&...)>::type;
```

[Example in compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/QwoxnA).

Once you start using C++17, you should replace `std::result_of` by `std::invoke_result` as described in the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of).

Comment: Note that [`std::result_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) is now deprecated (since C++17). From C++17 you should use [`std::invoke_result`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the solution you want using `declval` is this:

```
template <class F, class... Args>
void function(F&& f, Args&&... args)
{
    using type1 = decltype(std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    using type2 = decltype(std::forward<F>(declval<F>())(std::forward<Args>(declval<Args>())...));
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Start with this:

```
decltype(std::forward<F>(f)(std::forwards<Args>(args)...));
```

change to this:

```
decltype(std::declval<F>()(std::declval<Args>()...));
```

and done.  `std::declval<T>()` is a function with no implementation that has the same return type as `std::forward`.

[c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) has `std::result_of` (and [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) has `std::result_of_t`), but that has a few minor quirks that make it imperfect.  You can fix these quirks through use of `&&`:

```
std::result_of_t< F&&( Args&&... ) >
```

In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) they added `invoke_result` to fix those quirks:

```
std::invoke_result_t< F, Args... >
```

the quirks are because the types permitted in a function call signature are not all types, and the language silently adjusts them in certain ways (removes top-level const, doesn't permit some types to be returned, etc).